# Primality Test not working in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, primes

I have been trying to compact my code for a primality test in python so that it makes use of list comprehensions, but for some reason it doesn't return the correct results:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True
```

That's the code for my current primality test, but I want to condense it:

```
def isPrime(n):
if n > 1:
    return [False for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0]
    return True
```

I tried the above, but it outputs all non-prime integers up to n. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just FYI: Lots of prime-related code in Python: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~dstromberg/primes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want `False` if **any** lesser number is a divisor, code it directly that way:

```
def isPrime(n):
    return n<=1 or not any(i for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)
```

Note that this uses a **genexp**, not a **listcomp**, because that allows `any` to terminate the whole operation as soon as it finds any suitable `i` divisor and thus knows `n` cannot be prime.  List comprehensions generate an in-memory list of all their items, while generator expressions yield items one at a time, and only as long as they're being asked for "the next one" (by a `for` loop, an accumulator such as `any` or `all`, or directly by the `next` built-in).

Comment: `python -m timeit` is the best way to answer this and similar questions.  Put the alternative functions of interest with different names in `a.py`, and do `python -mtimeit -s'import a' 'a.isPrimeV1(248)'` and so forth.

Comment: `not any(i for i in range if condition)`? Was that really necessary? Why not `all(n%i for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1))`?

Comment: @Rawing, the two expressions are equivalent by De Morgan's theorem (extended to quantifiers); so neither can be "really necessary" as one can always substitute the other.  That's like asking if for two `int`s `a` and `b`, `a + b` "is really necessary" and "why not `b + a`"... a rather moot couple of questions:-).

Answer (score 2):

you can use `all`:

```
>>> def prime_check(n):
...     if n > 1:
...         return all(False for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)
... 
>>> prime_check(6)
False
>>> prime_check(23)
True
>>> prime_check(108)
False
>>> prime_check(111)
False
>>> prime_check(101)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a list containg `False` evaluates to a boolean `True`:

```
>>> isPrime(4)
[False]
>>> bool([False])
True
```